# Style textarea and button

Tags: css, html, google-chrome-extension

In a chrome extension (so feel free to make Chrome-specific suggestions), I'd like to make a textarea and a button on a single row. The textarea has a defined height (in rows). The button should be the same height as the textarea. Ideally some attribute or setting allows me to manually determine the width of the button versus the width of the textarea. Ideally this is just a css/html solution, not javascript if I can avoid it.

Comment: Sure, wheres your current code you have compiled so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use [flex box](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox) with

```
{ align-items:stretch }
```

Check this illustration: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/images/flex-align.svg

Comment: Great tip, flex boxes were indeed the answer. For what it's worth, all I actually needed was to style their parent (a div which contained nothing else) with `display: -webkit-flex`.

Comment: Then I played with the `-webkit-flex` for both the textarea and the button until it was _just_ right. So thank you so much for this.